# In solids physics, how are Van Der Waals forces modelled?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, solid-state-physics

I'd like to know how to treat VdW interactions among layers. Specifically I'm using Quantum Espresso and I'd like to know how VdW forces are implemented in the Kohn-Sham equation. Does it insert a $V \propto \frac{1}{r^6}$ in the effective potential?

Comment: This discussion should be relevant (https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/difference-between-van-der-waals-dft-d-and-dft-d3-corrections-in-ab-initio-cal?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, VdW effects are implemented in QE as a corrective factor in the total energy, $E_{DFT-D}=E_{DFT}+E_{VdW}$. The exact form of $E_{VdW}$ depends on which type of correction you choose but almost all of them have the $1/r^6$ dependence. You can find the exact form in the references given in the input description of [vdw_corr](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#idm656).

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation for `pw.x`](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html), version 7.2, lists several different ways to compute van der Waals corrections:

- Grimme's semiempirical DFT-D2 and DFT-D3;
- Tkatchenko–Scheffler *ab initio* vdW;
- many-body dispersion (MBD); and
- the exchange-hole dipole-moment model (XDM).

Each of these will compute the forces differently, but the references in the documentation will detail each one.

In addition, [various nonlocal van der Waals functionals](https://gitlab.com/QEF/q-e/-/blob/develop/Modules/funct.f90?ref_type=heads) have been implemented, with names mostly of the form `vdw-DF*` (this is in the file `Modules/funct.f90`). Again, references to the papers are included in the comments of that file.